# Creating Table with attributes that has % sign

Tags: sql

while creating a table i have faced a problem giving percentage. How to give that? Could anyone please help? I am sharing the part.

The field should be evaluated numerically and interpreted as a percentage (e.g. it should be possible to save that one author only contributed 10% to a book, while another 90%).  There is explicitly no provision for checking whether the sum of the shares of all authors in a book is 100%.

Comment: Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use.Percentages are usually stored as fix-point decimal numbers. Check out the documentation of your chosen rdbms on such data types.

Answer (score 0):

One option is just to give each author a weight and then assign the proportion when you query:

```
select ba.authorid,
       ba.weight * 1.0 / sum(ba.weight) over (partition by ba.bookid) as author_ratio
from bookauthors ba;
```

This guarantees that all authors sum to exactly 100% of the book.